# Problema con variable global

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo

Estoy preparando un examen y llevo haciendo varios ejercicios, el problema me surge cuando llego a la parte de la programación orientada a objetos (POO) en este ejercicio:

> Escribir una clase que permita representar al personaje de un videojuego.
>   Un personaje tiene un nombre (o nickname), un porcentaje de vida (o salud),
>   un poder (su nombre, por ejemplo, “patada giratoria”),
>   y una medida de daño (número entero entre 0 y 100).
>
> 1. Implementar un método que permite imprimir la información de un personaje utilizando la instrucción   print()
> 2. Implementar un método que permite atacar a otro personaje (que se recibe cómo parámetro).
>      El ataque del personaje (p1) le quita vida al personaje que es atacado (p2),
>      utilizando la siguiente función:
>      nueva_vida(p2) = vida_actual(p2) - medida_de_daño(p1)
> 3. Implementar un método que indica (devolviendo True) si un personaje está con vida (salud > 0)
> 4. Crear 3 personajes llamados pj1, pj2 y pj3 (con el porcentaje de salud y poder que ustedes desee),
>      pj1 debe atacar a pj2 y pj3
>      """

Éste es el código que llevo:

```
global  vida_queda
vida_queda = 0
class Personaje:

    def __init__(self, nickname, vida, poder, daño):
        self.nickname = nickname
        self.vida = vida
        self.poder = poder
        self.daño = daño

    def __repr__(self):
        return("su nombre era " + self.nickname + " " + "se decia que habia vivido " + " " +  self.vida + " "+ "tantos años" + " " + "su ataque especial era" +" "+ self.poder + " " + "y el daño que infligian era " + " " +self.daño)


    def atacar(self,atacante):
        vida_queda = int(self.vida) - int(atacante.daño)  #Tuve que usar el método int() para que funcionara  
        return( vida_queda)


    def checklife(self):
        if vida_queda <= 0:  #Tuve que usar el método int() para que funcionara
            return("i'm dead")
        else:
            return(vida_queda)        

p1 = Personaje("el_gaucho", str(100), "mono borracho", str(30))
print(p1)
print(p1.nickname)
print(p1.vida)
print(p1.poder)
print(p1.daño)
print("#_________________________________________________________#")

p2 = Personaje("'gaucho_Bataraz'", str(30), "facón giratorio", str(250))
print(p2)
print(p2.nickname)
print(p2.vida)
print(p2.poder)
print(p2.daño)

print("#_________________________________________________________#")
p3 = Personaje("'Dura'", "120", "golpe de campo", "300")
print(p3)
print(p3.nickname)
print(p3.vida)
print(p3.poder)
print(p3.vida)
```

Mi problema es que siempre me devuelve `i'm dead`, cuando claramente he probado atacar a un personaje con mucha vida con uno con muy poco daño, ¿hay alguna
forma de que se guarde la variable o no es así?

Comment: Lo he ejecutado y no veo el problema. Mira el resultado aquí https://repl.it/@vperezher/RareYouthfulComputing

Comment: pero mira este paso     p3.atacar(p1)
=> 90
   p3.checklife()
=> "i'm dead"
  deberia devolverme vida_queda

Comment: Estás usando vida_queda como una variable global ¿la vida de quién entonces? Sería mejor que fuera un atributo de un objeto

Comment: de cualquier personaje de esa clase, vida_queda es lo que le queda de vida al personaje luego de ser atacado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema está causado por la variable global `vida_queda`. En general no se recomienda el uso de variables globales.

La solución más elegante a tu problema consiste en hacer que `vida_queda` sea un atributo más de cada uno de los objetos, inicializándolo en `__init__()` con `self.vida_queda=0` (y no te olvides de poner delante `self.` cuando lo modifiques en `atacar()` y lo compruebes en `checklife()`.

**EDICIÓN** Releyendo el enunciado, me doy cuenta de que quizás la variable `vida_queda` no sea necesaria, y lo que debe hacer el método `atacar()` es simplemente decrementar `self.vida` (y ese mismo atributo sería el que se comprueba desde `checklife()`.

### Explicación adicional

Si además quieres saber por qué no te funcionaba cuando era una variable global, sigue leyendo, pero te advierto que nos metemos en "profundidades".

Cuando inicializas una variable fuera de toda función, se le llama una "variable global". Estas variables pueden usarse después desde cualquiera de las funciones del mismo módulo **peero**...  si en una de esas funciones intentas modificar el valor de esa variable, entonces python creará otra variable *local* en lugar de cambiar el valor de la global.

Por ello, cuando en `atacar()` intentas cambiar el valor de `vida_queda`, en realidad se estará creando una variable local con el mismo nombre, dentro de esa función. Por eso, al comprobar el valor desde la función `checklife()` te da por muerto, porque la variable global `vida_queda` no ha sido modificada y sigue siendo cero.

Para evitar ese extraño comportamiento, puedes poner dentro de la función `atacar()` una línea que diga `global vida_queda`. Esto le dice a Python que modifique la variable global en lugar de crear una nueva local.

Comment: ya lo solucione, muchas gracias comunidad

Comment: @noobprogramer De nada. Recuerda aceptar la respuesta si te ha ayudado

Comment: como hago eso, osea aceptar la respuesta

Comment: @noobprogramer Bajo el contador de puntos de la respuesta deberías ver una marca gris que al pincharla se vuelve verde.

Comment: gracias..........